# Enumerate OData Service Data Context

Tags: c#, odata, enumerate

I have a OData service that returns a list of sharepoint lists.
I am unable to enumerate this list.

Is it possible to enumerate this to be able to loop through the lists in this Context in a foreach loop?

```
public class ODService
{
    private DataContext _Context;
    private NetworkCredential _nc;

    public DataContext Context { get { return _Context; } }

    /// <summary>
    /// Constructor creates the context for access to sharepoint
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="UserName">Service Account User Name</param>
    /// <param name="Password">Service Account Password</param>
    /// <param name="uri">Service uri</param>
    public ODService(string UserName, string Password, string uri)
    {
        SetNetworkCredentials(UserName, Password);
        SetContext(uri);
    }

    private void SetContext(string uri)
    {
        _Context = new DataContext(new Uri(uri));
        _Context.Credentials = _nc;
        _Context.MergeOption = MergeOption.NoTracking;

    }

    private void SetNetworkCredentials(string UserName, string Password)
    {
        _nc = new NetworkCredential(UserName, Password);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Got it:

```
    public IList<string> EntityList()
    {
        IList<string> PropertyList = new List<string>();

        var Properties = typeof(DataContext).GetProperties();
        foreach (var property in Properties)
        {
            PropertyList.Add(property.Name);
        }

        return PropertyList;
    }
```